# what's the type of System.Char.m_value

Tags: c#, types, char

In reference code `NDP/clr/src/BCL/System/Char.cs`:

```
public struct Char : IComparable, IConvertible
{
    //
    // Member Variables
    //
    internal char m_value;
```

But isn't `char` an alias of `System.Char`? I'm confused.

Comment: What is your question exactly? Yes, `char` is an alias for `System.Char`. Are you asking something like how `Char` can have a field as typed itself? I'm sure there is a duplicate of this question for `Int32` type but as always I couldn't find it.

Comment: The CLR has special knowledge of some types. Their cs source isn't necessarily reflective of reality.

Comment: so does that mean each Char instance has another Char instance "m_value" embedded inside it?

Comment: @SonerGönül Yes. That's what confusing me.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Does that mean the type "char" of "m_value" is not an alias of System.char but some internal char type?

Answer (score 0):

`char` is a C# type that matches the .NET type `System.Char`.

See a list of built-in C# types and their corresponding .NET types: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds.aspx